# Regex results in SyntaxError: unterminated parenthetical

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to use regex on the jsf (.xhtml) page. When i want to use regex i keep getting this error

```
 SyntaxError: unterminated parenthetical
```

and my code is

```
var data2 = ($("#data").val()).replace(/User(/g,"{");
```

I use regex earlier in php pages but never get such error.

Comment: To match a literal `(`  you need to escape it, `/User\(/g`.